# Need to overwrite a DLL in inno setup installer - but file not getting replaced

Tags: windows, dll, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup for installing patch updates for my VB.net application where I have to replace a DLL file and a couple of javascript/html files for the update. However, the DLL doesn't get updated (it is in C:\program files...) - even on XP systems without UAC it doesnt get replaced, but when I manually delete the DLL and rerun the patch, the file gets copied. It is not readonly, and no UAC/admin privilege is involved in the XP case.

What could be the reason that the file doesn't get copied if a file already exists? It is built in VS2008 and in .NET 2.0 - the new DLL has a more recent date and size difference too.

Is there a way to workaround the UAC write access issue on Vista/Win7/8? I guess the patch would never succeed to replace the file on these systems with UAC on. Telling our user base to turn it off is obviously not an option.

[EDIT] The dll assembly is packaged into the setup.exe within Visual Studio by picking it up from the Release folder on building the solution. The inno setup iss [File] section has this:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Setup5\Setup5\Debug\setup.exe; DestDir: {app}
Source: C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Setup5\Setup5\Debug\interact.msi; DestDir: {app}
[Run]
Filename: {app}\setup.exe; Flags: runmaximized
```

Comment: Could you show your `[Files]` section entry for that library ? What do you mean by *"Is there a way to workaround the UAC write access issue on Vista/Win7/8 ?"*, what issue do you think of ?

Comment: Ideally I want the patch update to happen without any human interaction - ie. I can't have them clicking on a dialogue asking for admin permission (UAC?) when I'm trying to move or delete files such as the DLL.

Comment: If you're going to update/install files in `Program Files` directory on Windows Vista up, you'll just have to ask for admin privileges, otherwise you fail on access denied error and for this case you shouldn't explicitly specify the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) directive value (by default requires admin privileges).

Comment: If the dll is within the setup.exe, you have to fix setup.exe, since is it which fails to replace the dll. The only other thing you can do is to delete the dll, but that's not a good choice because something can fail afterwards and the target machine will end without the original dll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the DLL have a version resource?  Is the new DLL a higher version than the old one?  By default, InnoSetup uses the version resource to determine if a file should be replaced.
Another option is that you could add the `ignoreversion` flag in the `[Files]` section to always replace that file.

Comment: From what I can see, the DLL in the Visual Studio setup solution has no version resource. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why are you building a Visual Studio Setup solution and then including that within an InnoSetup install?  Why not just include the DLL directly within the InnoSetup install or just use the Visual Studio Setup?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance - this was developed by a third party and i'm trying to fix production issues.